# $this->post codeigniter don't work with rest api

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, post

I tried to work with `$this->post()` to get data sent by post in json format. By I can not get any result of for example `$this->post('name')`.

This is the code :

```
<?php

require(APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class user_api extends REST_Controller {

    function user_post() {

                $user = array(
                    'id' => null,
                    'firstname' => $this->post('firstname'),
                    'lastname' => $this->post('lastname')
                );

                $result = $this->user_model->insert($user);
                if ($result) {
                    $this->response($result, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
                } else {
                    $this->response(NULL, 404);
                }
    }

}

?>
```

data sent on json format to the link  : http://mydomain.com/myapplication/user_api/user :

```
{"firstname":"test",
"lastname":"test"
}
```

There is no data in the database like it can not get data from `$this->post('firstname')`.

Any idea ????

Answer (score 10):

json data you can't get through post method you have to use like this

```
require(APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class user_api extends REST_Controller {

    function user_post() {

       $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

        $user = array(
            'id' => null,
            'firstname' => $params['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $params['lastname']
        );

        $result = $this->user_model->insert($user);
        if ($result) {
            $this->response($result, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
        } else {
            $this->response(NULL, 404);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//You should use

$array=array(
'firstName'   => $this->input->post("firstName"),
'lastName'   => $this->input->post("lastName")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the correct function to get the values you want the posted data but you are trying to get in `$this->post('name')`

you should use the CI's method to get the values like

```
$this->input->post('name');
```

or

```
$this->input->get('name');


            $user = array(
                'id' => null,
                'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname')
            );
```

You should  take a look at [Input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

With CodeIgniter you access post variables like so

```
$this->input->post('variable_name');
```

Also if you have

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

in your config file it will stop cross-site scripting so be careful of that

Answer (score 0):

When you pass arguments in the URL for POST to `CI RestController`, you need to use 
`$this->input->get('id')` instead of `$this->get('id')` [i.e if id is passed in the url].

`$this->get('id')` does not work with POST URL argument (ex: `http://abcd.xyz.com/get_stuff?id=1`).

Although, `$this->get('id')` seems to work with GETs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,while writing webservice with REST in codeigniter.

Solution ==> You should set content-type in header request.

-Since you are sending post data in json format you should set content-type to application/json

-If you are testing your response in any rest client set content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 0):

```
     $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
      header('Content-type: application/json');
      $obj = json_decode($postdata,true);
      $firstname=$obj['firstname'];
      $lastname=$obj['lastname']; and pass to an array
```

Answer (score 0):

**IN REST API**

=> If you want to get data from server using get method then use below code

```
$user = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('http://example.com/index.php/api/user/id/1/format/json')
);

echo $user->name;
```

=> If you want to Insert/Update data to server then you need to use form action like below

```
<form method="post" id="validateFrm" action="http://example.com/index.php/api/create">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" id="name" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="text" class="input-field" name="email" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="row last-row">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Now You can use all form element in your controller/method like

```
$name = $this->post('name');
$email = $this->post('email');
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Here two type of condition exists. 
If you getting data from server then need to set format:

[FOR REST Client]

```
$this->rest->format('application/json');
```

[FOR Android Volley]

```
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

If you sending data from client to server then need to set format:
[FOR REST Client]

```
$this->rest->format('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

[FOR Android Volley]

```
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should code like this:

```
$data=array{

'firstname' => $this->input->('firstname'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email')
}

$this->user_model->update($data);*emphasized text*
```