# API rest codeigniter POST method return null

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, post

I am using Phil Sturgeons `RESTFUL` libraries for codeigniter.
But I have a problem with POST method.

> $this->post('name');

The code above always return null when I try catch the value.

here is my request :
`Request Url: http://localhost/api_rest/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400
Params: {
    "email": "example@email.com",
    "password": "balbala"
}` :

```
function login_post()
{ 
if(!$this->post('email') || !$this->post('password')){
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Email and Password leave blank'),400);
    }
```

yups it's return status code : `400 because $this->post('email') or $this->post('password')` absolutely return `false`.

and maybe you should know my error :

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Format.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 230</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  simplexml_load_string(): email=sahal%40seratuscompany.com&amp;password=123456</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Format.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 230</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  simplexml_load_string(): ^</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Format.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 230</p>

</div>{"error":"Email and Password leave blank"}
```

anyone have an idea about this stuff.?

Comment: Have you tried dumping $_POST to see if the request is being received properly at your end?

Comment: oh,,oke i will try it..
but i am a little sure it return null too..

Comment: Try var_dump($_POST) as well as var_dump($this->post()). If they are both returning nulls, that means your script is not receiving POST variables.

Comment: I tried with var_dump($_POST) and still return `array(0) {
}`..
actually my class extend to REST_Controller not to CI_controller, i think probably it's the problem,,but if i use GET method it's completely working..

Comment: I use the same class and it works fine. It looks like you aren't posting the data. Try var_dump on $_REQUEST to see if your data shows up there. Most likely your request is not being sent properly.

Comment: ya maybe i'm not posting the data,,do you have any suggestion tools for testing rest API? i currently using rest console v.4.0.2 chrome plugin and get a little confuse to include POST value on that..

Comment: I just use firebug to make sure the requests that are going out are fine. It's a bit easier to inspect the XHR request on firebug than it is on Chrome (for me)

Answer (score 0):

add

> } else {
>
> $this->response(_$SERVER); }

or

> } else { $this->response(_$POST); }

to see what is being sent to the method.

Comment: i think he has the same problem like me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490174/this-post-codeigniter-dont-work-with-rest-api?rq=1

$this->response(_$SERVER); return error because it doesn't recognize with PHP. it tried $this->response($_SERVER); but it doesn't give a response.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
     $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
      header('Content-type: application/json');
      $obj = json_decode($postdata,true);
      $email=$obj['email'];
      $password=$obj['password'];
      then do the rest
```